# CUDA device to host copy very slow

Tags: c++, performance, cuda, copy, device

I'm running windows 7 64 bits, cuda 4.2, visual studio 2010.

First, I run some code on cuda, then download the data back to host. Then do some processing and move back to the device.
Then I did the following copy from device to host, it runs very fast, like 1ms.

```
clock_t start, end;
count=1000000;
thrust::host_vector <int> h_a(count);
thrust::device_vector <int> d_b(count,0);
int *d_bPtr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_b[0]);
start=clock();
thrust::copy(d_b.begin(), d_b.end(), h_a.begin());
end=clock();
cout<<"Time Spent:"<<end-start<<endl;
```

It takes ~1ms to finish.

Then I ran some other code on the cuda again, mainly atomic operations. Then I copy the data from device to host, it takes very long time， like ~9s.

```
__global__ void dosomething(int *d_bPtr)
{
....
atomicExch(d_bPtr,c)
....
}

start=clock();
thrust::copy(d_b.begin(), d_b.end(), h_a.begin());
end=clock();
cout<<"Time Spent:"<<end-start<<endl;
```

~ 9s

I ran the code multiple times, for example

```
int i=0;
while (i<10)
{
clock_t start, end;
count=1000000;
thrust::host_vector <int> h_a(count);
thrust::device_vector <int> d_b(count,0);
int *d_bPtr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_b[0]);
start=clock();
thrust::copy(d_b.begin(), d_b.end(), h_a.begin());
end=clock();
cout<<"Time Spent:"<<end-start<<endl;

__global__ void dosomething(int *d_bPtr)
{
....
atomicExch(d_bPtr,c)
....
}

start=clock();
thrust::copy(d_b.begin(), d_b.end(), h_a.begin());
end=clock();
cout<<"Time Spent:"<<end-start<<endl;
i++
}
```

The results are pretty much the same.
What could be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious, Are you calling atomicExch at the host side programming or device function? atomicExch can only be called in the device function/kernel.

Comment: I still dont understand how are you able to use `thrust::raw_ptr_cast` with `device_vector` first index.I am trying to run a snippet from your code and I am getting `error: argument list for class template "thrust::device_ptr" is missing` error...

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. it should be int *device_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_b[0]); I will update it. Do you think it is this one causing problem?? Or should I directly use d_b.begin() as the input for the atomic operation? Thank you!

Comment: could you post the shortest reproducer you can come up with.  I tried making a simple example from your code but didn't see anything wrong.  There are various odd syntax errors in your code, so it would help to have a compilable reproducer.

Comment: I'm really sorry, it is my bad. I didn't bring my source code. I will follow talonmies's suggestions, re-run the test again. And also post a complilable code as soon as possible tomorrow. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is one of timing, not of any change in copy performance. Kernel launches are asynchronous in CUDA, so what you are measuring is not just the time for `thrust::copy` but also for the prior kernel you launched to complete. If you change you code for timing the copy operation to something like this:

```
cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // wait until prior kernel is finished
start=clock();
thrust::copy(d_b.begin(), d_b.end(), h_a.begin());
end=clock();
cout<<"Time Spent:"<<end-start<<endl;
```

You should find the transfer times are restored to their previous performance. So you real question isn't "why is `thrust::copy` slow", it is "why is my kernel slow". And based on the rather terrible pseudo code you posted, the answer is "because it is full of `atomicExch()` calls which serialise kernel memory transactions".

Comment: Thank you talonmies!!I will follow your suggestions and run the code again tomorrow to see. Sorry for the terrible pseudo code. I'm new to cuda and I don't have my source code available now... Thank you very much!!

Comment: I tested today, talonmies was completely right!! Everything is the same as what he described!! Thank you very much!

Comment: @UserKiwi: If this answered your question then perhaps you would be so kind as to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/163653). This marks the question as completed.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to use **cudpp**, in my opinion is faster than thrust (I'm writing master thesis about optimization and I tried both libraries). If copy is very slow, you can try to write your own kernel to copy data.