# performance tuning a thrust application

Tags: c++, performance, thrust, benchmarking

I am running a small C++/thrust program (below) on my macbook pro w/ 9600M GT gpu and am interested in understanding where the time is spent in the function h, because the goal is to run this code as quickly as possible for larger values of NEPS.

For that purpose, I have littered the function with clock() calls.

The times printed indicate that almost all of the time is spent in thrust::reduce.
Indeed, the reported time for thrust::reduce is several hundred times greater than that for thrust::transform, which invokes three calls to cosine per element.  Why?

Naturally, I'm suspicious of the measured times.
I inserted a 2nd call to thrust::reduce just to see if the time reported would be similar:  it's not.  The time reported for the 2nd call has much higher variance and is smaller.
More confusion:  why?

I had also tried using thrust::transform_reduce (commented out) in place of the two kernel calls expecting that to run faster -- instead, it was 4% slower.  Why?

Suggestions appreciated!

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


 float NEPS = 6.0;
 __device__ float EPS;
 __device__ float SQEPS;

 __device__ float CNV_win;
 __device__ float CNV_dt;
 int CNV_n;
 float EU_dt;

__host__ __device__ float f(float x,float t){
    return x*cos(t)+x*cos(t/SQEPS)+cos(t/EPS);
}

struct h_functor
{
  const float x, t;
  h_functor(float _x, float _t) : x(_x),t(_t) {}
  __host__ __device__
  float operator()(const float & t_f) const {
    return f(x,   t-CNV_win+CNV_dt*(t_f+1)   )*CNV_dt;
  } 
};


clock_t my_clock() __attribute__ ((noinline));
clock_t my_clock() {
  return clock();
}
float h(float x,float t){
    float sum;

    sum = CNV_dt*(f(x,t-CNV_win/2)+f(x,t+CNV_win/2))/2;
    clock_t start = my_clock(), diff1, diff2, diff3, diff4, diff5;
    thrust::device_vector<float> t_f(CNV_n-2);
    diff1 = my_clock() - start;
    /* initialize t_f to 0.. CNV_n-3 */
    start = my_clock();
    thrust::sequence(t_f.begin(), t_f.end());
    diff2 = my_clock() - start;

    start = my_clock();
    thrust::transform(t_f.begin(), t_f.end(), t_f.begin(), h_functor(x,t));
    diff3 = my_clock() - start;
    start = my_clock();
    sum += thrust::reduce(t_f.begin(), t_f.end());
    diff4 = my_clock() - start;
    start = my_clock();
    sum += thrust::reduce(t_f.begin(), t_f.end());
    diff5 = my_clock() - start;
#define usec(d) (d)
    fprintf(stderr, "Time taken %ld %ld %ld %ld %ld usecs\n", usec(diff1), usec(diff2), usec(diff3), usec(diff4), usec(diff5));
        /* a bit slower, surprisingly:
       sum += thrust::transform_reduce(t_f.begin(), t_f.end(), h_functor(x,t), 0, thrust::plus<float>());
       */

    return sum;
}
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  if (argc >= 1) NEPS = strtod(argv[1], 0);
  fprintf(stderr, "NEPS = %g\n", NEPS);

  EPS= powf(10.0,-NEPS);
  SQEPS= powf(10.0,-NEPS/2.0);
  CNV_win= powf(EPS,1.0/4.0);
  CNV_dt = EPS;
  CNV_n = powf(EPS,-3.0/4.0);
  EU_dt = powf(EPS,3.0/4.0);

  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(CNV_win, &CNV_win, sizeof(float));
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(CNV_dt, &CNV_dt, sizeof(float));
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(SQEPS, &SQEPS, sizeof(float));
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(EPS, &EPS, sizeof(float));

  float x=1.0;
  float t = 0.0;
  int n = floor(1.0/EU_dt);
  fprintf(stderr, "CNV_n = %d\n", CNV_n);
  while (n--) {
    float sum = h(x,t);
    x=x+EU_dt*sum;
    t=t+EU_dt;
  }
  printf("%f\n",x);
}
```

Comment: Read [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12793124/1410711) answer.It might be useful to your code.

Comment: @abinhole:  thanks! adding cudaDeviceSynchronize() calls before the clock calls produces much more plausible results.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an option to use arrayfire if you want to optimize your algorithm for performance. I took the liberty to rewrite your code for arrayfire, which you can compare with thrust version and choose whichever runs faster:

```
float h(float x,float t){

 float sum = CNV_dt * (f(x, t - CNV_win/2) + f(x, t + CNV_win/2)) / 2;
 // initialize t_f with a sequence 0..CNV_n-3
 af::array t_f(af::seq(0, CNV_n-3));

 // transform vector on the GPU
 t_f =  t - CNV_win + CNV_dt*(t_f+1); 
 t_f = (x*cos(t_f) + x*cos(t_f/SQEPS) + cos(t_f/EPS)) * CNV_dt;

 sum += af::sum<float>(t_f); // sum up all elements of the vector
 return sum;
}
```

Also, note that there is no need to copy variables explicitly to the GPU (i.e. no need for cudaMemcpyToSymbol calls)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to do not use clock() function in multi-core environment. It is prune to give wrong answers.

It is better to use wall clock time [clock_gettime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506952/understanding-the-different-clocks-of-clock-gettime/7506987#7506987). Also at Windows we have some high resolution timers.

- [High resolution timer in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749621/high-resolution-timer-in-linux)
- [High resolution timer at Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825720/c-high-precision-time-measurement-in-windows)

  - ["Example code"](http://cplus.about.com/od/howtodothingsi2/a/timing.htm)

While working with CUDA, it might be better to use the timers that are provided by CUDA itself. cutil_timer

- [Cost of initialization of CUDA device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704681/cuda-cutil-timer-confusion-on-elapsed-time)
- [CUDA's timer at CUDA 5.0](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/ucacbbl/cuda5/)