# Optimal datastructure for cudamemcopy

Tags: arrays, struct, cuda

Is there an optimal data structure to transfer data using cudamemcopy(... , devicetohost)?  I've found that arrays work a lot faster than structs.  Is there a reason for this and is there a more optimal method?

edit -

It seems that my timing wasn't being recorded correctly.  The amount of time for the structs and arrays should be about equal.  I will try using the cuda events api to record the time.

Comment: as long as the data is contiguous and can be transferred using a single pointer, there is no difference what the underlying data arrangement is.  If the data is not contiguous but orderly, cudaMemcpy2D may help. A single cudaMemcpy call resolves everything to a pointer and a sequence of bytes after that pointer to transfer.  So there should be no difference between an array of ints and an array of structs, for example, as long as the total number of bytes is the same.  Now, if the array of structs has padding or otherwise unused space in the struct, then that will be less efficient

Comment: The data is contiguous in the struct.  The struct has four ints and one float.  I allocated an array of this struct onto the gpu. I also have an array that is 5x as large.  I allocated that onto the gpu as well.  When I copied the memory back from the gpu onto the cpu, the array, which has more bytes than the struct, transferred faster than the struct.  So I am under the impression that arrays can be copied faster from memory from the device to host.  Do you have any trouble shooting ideas that can help verify this?

Comment: Your method of timing the copy operations may be faulty.  It's a common mistake when timing operations after a kernel call (e.g. memcopy of data from the gpu to the cpu) to not take into account that the kernel call returns control to the host immediately, but the copy operation does not start till the kernel is complete.  Please post (edit your question) a simple, complete, compilable example that demonstrates the timing discrepancy.  Are you using cuda event api to do the timing?

Comment: You're right.  I'm using gettimeofday() function in linux to get the time outputs.  I'm not taking into account the kernel execution time.

Comment: If you just want sane copy timings, you can [add a cudaDeviceSynchronize()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792693/cuda-device-to-host-copy-very-slow) after your kernel call, before the gettimeofday check prior to the copy.  But in general you'll be less likely to get tripped up by this if you use the [cuda event api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676102/strategies-for-timing-cuda-kernels-pros-and-cons) for timing.  It's pretty easy.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I added the cudaDeviceSynchronize() and it shows that it is my kernel that's actually slow.  Does this issue with timing only occur right after kernel calls?

Comment: I'm sure if I answered this question one way or another somebody would point out an exception.  Fundamentally the GPU is  asynchronous with respect to the CPU.  Any call that returns immediately (kernels are not the only ones, eg. cudaMemcpyAsync) will have this hazard.  Use the event api instead, which understands the asynchronous nature of the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Structure-of-Arrays are usually better than Arrays-of-Structs when loading data from/to global memory into shared/registers when in the kernel. However, I don't think there is any performance difference between SoA and AoS when copying the data from/to host to/from device (in one big memcopy transaction). After all, the amount of data is the same.

The only exception is if some extra padding bytes are added at the end of the struct to achieve certain memory alignment of the elements of the AoS.

I think there might be some other reason why you are experiencing performance differences.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I am skeptical that the performance difference is due to the copy.

Perhaps your data structure is being aligned in a way that there are empty gaps.

A second cause could be due to memory page alignment handling. When you get memory using malloc it can be fragmented similar to the layout of the Windows filesystems. The level of fragmentation can very, but it is not unreasonable to say that if you do a single call to malloc you get memory that is continuously aligned, while if you do many calls, you can get memory with gaps.

CUDA's memory copy has to deal with this additional overhead by checking the pages one by one and manually moving them to the GPU.

---

The real solution to your problem will be using `cudaMallocHost` to allocate memory that the CPU doesn't have to worry about. Try doing this and see if it fixes your problem.